# BSOD (SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION) on Win 10 when using VMware or Virtual Box

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bsod, vmware

I've been working with VMware on Windows 10 for several years now. But now there's the problem that I get a BlueScreen when I start "Windows XP 64 Bit". But Android-VMs (Nox Player) and Linux-VMs still work fine.

I could even reinstall Windows XP in Virtual Box, but as soon as the installation process is finished and it's booting from the virtual disk my host just crashes.

> Yes, I have already disabled Hyper-V and Windows Sandbox, etc..
>   I also used the "sfc /scannow" command and other similar checks.

My specs:

- Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit / 10.0.18362 Build 18362 / 1903
- AMD FX 8320 (4.2 GHz OC)
- MSI Radeon RX 480
- 16 GB DDR3 RAM
- 1x SSD (win10) 1x HDD (data)

Minidump Analysis:

```
SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000080000004, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff801230ad390, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffffa07feae4930, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.
```

[Download full minidump](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=71244212969527555437)

Please help me :)

Comment: You can have only one VM system installed on your pc and use it, because the software claims direct access to your hardware. It sounds like NOX Player is your primary VM system and VMWare and OracleVM are fighting NOX Player. Try disabling NOX player's services and see if that resolves your issue

Comment: I just tried to start Nox Player but I got the same Bluescreen.I don't think it has something to do with hardware claims because I installed Virtual Box after I got my first BSOD with VMware Player.

Comment: Are you using Avast/AVG by any chance? See here https://superuser.com/questions/1460590/virtualbox-ubuntu-18-04-lts-causing-bsod-amd-ryzen-7-3750h/1460657#1460657

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I was using Avast AV and disabling the virtualisation option worked.